# How can I change WooCommerce checkout page order summery section style?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am new to WordPress. I need to change the checkout page style. Please help me to give suggestions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this wordpress plugin in order to customize your checkout page style/CSS: https://wordpress.org/plugins/postpage-specific-custom-css/ . You can use description and installation tabs to learn how to download the plugin to your wordpress.

You'll notice the blue *download* button on the right-side of the screen when you're ready to start the installation process.

You can also use the screenshots with the description tab to view how to use the plugin.

The plugin would be easier to use than altering the CSS style within the *appearance* section of your wordpress dashboard.